# Difference between empty? and nil? methods

Tags: ruby

Can you explain why empty? and nil? methods return different results?

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > [].empty?
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > {}.nil?
 => false 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > {}.empty?
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > [].empty?
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > [].nil?
 => false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you are coming from python? Python and other languages can be quite loose about tests for various design reasons.

Ruby takes the strict approach.

nil? is only for testing nil (no value).

empty? is testing for containers (arrays, hashes) that have nothing in them.

Search for ruby documentation on those methods. For example, [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-empty-3F) is empty for array.

You might also like [this tutorial](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/basictutorial.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Because empty and nil are different concepts?? :)

**Empty?** -> There's nothing here

**Nil?** -> Null

Answer (score 1):

your question is completely discovered here: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/160638

Answer (score 1):

`empty?` returns whether the object is "empty", by whatever definition applies to that object. Not all objects respond to `empty?`. For example, [for Array, `empty?` is defined as](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-empty-3F):

> Returns `true` if `self` contains no elements.
>
> `[].empty?   #=> true`

Whereas `nil?` only returns true if it called on [`nil`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/NilClass.html) itself. You can see this in the [implementation of `nil?` in Object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-nil-3F) where it always returns `false`, and [in NilClass](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/NilClass.html#method-i-nil-3F) where it always returns `true`.

```
[1].empty?      #=> false
[].empty?       #=> true
Object.new.nil? #=> false
nil.nil?        #=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

`empty?`, as the name suggests, tests whether an object is *empty*, not `nil`. The object doesn't necessarily implement `empty?`, either. On the other hand, `nil?` tests if some instance is `nil` (again, as the name suggests) - not if it's empty.

```
nil.nil? # true; yup, it's nil. Calling .empty? will result in an error.
anythingElse.nil? # false, it's not nil.
[1, 2].empty? # false; 2 elements
{"blah" => 2}.empty? # false, it has stuff
```

`nil` is a nothing object, not an empty array.